# php or jquery script to fetch the visitors country code for my prestashop site

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

In my prestashop site i want to know the country/country code of my website visitors.If a visitor open my website i want show an alert as from which country he is opening my site.Is there any php or jquery script available to get the country code of a visitor?

Comment: Doesn't google gave you some results???

Comment: I have tried with few links but i cant get the proper output.https://snipt.net/raw/93b686d15b425b72ce283ef058418c35/?nice and http://www.webtechriser.com/tutorials/79-webmaster/80-how-do-you-detect-a-website-visitor-s-country

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/KNkk4/

Comment: Fiddle is not working.I have placed the script in my site header.tpl file and verified too.no alert message.whether i need to include anything else?@A.Wolff

Comment: Fiddle works as expected for me, i don't know what's going wrong on your side

Comment: I have verified the fiddle in private window thats why i cant see the alert sorry.But i have placed the same code in my prestashop header.tpl file of my site but there is no alert in my site.why is it so?@A.Wolff

Comment: I cannot devine it, i'm sorry... Check your console, you should have some error. And before you get any other issue, remember, ajax is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on user ip address we can show the location

Try this

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
     alert(response.loc);
}, "jsonp");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rBL3D/9/)

For Country Code,Name

```
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  alert(location.country_code);
  alert(location.country_name);
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KNkk4/1/)

Comment: Hi i need the country code of my website visitor.If any user open my prestashop website i want to show the country name in an alert box.@Sridhar

Comment: @user3489161 is above code working or not?

Comment: Yes its working but its not working in my site @Sridhar

Comment: @You have to load jquery in head section and add this script

Comment: Yes i got it.I have placed this script above my jquery file now i changed the location script at bottom its working.can u pls tell how to fetch this country code and store it in a variable?@Sridhar

Comment: `var code = location.country_name`  code contains the value

Comment: Hi as i am a beginner i was not able to confirm the value stored in code using echo.how to confirm country_name using echo statement@Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIP(){
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip = getIP();

$loc_content = file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&ip=$ip&format=json");
$loc_content = json_decode($loc_content);

$code = $loc_content->countryCode;
```